# Is it possible to dynamically add tabs in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

Is it possible to dynamically add tabs in blackberry application?

I have found this piece of code that works for java but when i try doing for blackberry in BB JDE it doesnt give any result.

```
final TabSheet tabSheet = new TabSheet();

Button button = new Button("Add the tab");
button.addListener(
    new Button.ClickListener(){
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
            content.addComponent(new Label("This is the tab content."));
            Tab tab = tabSheet.addTab(content, "The new Tab", null);
        }
     }
);
```

I implemented in blackberry this way

```
final TabSheet tabSheet = new TabSheet();
ButtonField button = new ButtonField("Add the tab");
button.setChangeListener(
    new FieldChangeListener() 
    {
        public void fieldChanged(Field field,int context) 
        {
            VerticalFieldManager content = new VerticalFieldManager();
            content.addComponent(new LabelField("This is the tab content."));
            Tab tab = tabSheet.addTab(content, "The new Tab", null);
        }
    }
);
```

There is something wrong with use of "tabsheet" identifiers.  What would be their substitute way in blackberry?

**Update:**

```
final PaneManagerModel tabsheet = new PaneManagerModel();
ButtonField button = new ButtonField("Add the tab");
button.setChangeListener(
    new FieldChangeListener() 
    {
        public void fieldChanged(Field field,int context) 
        {
            VerticalFieldManager content = new VerticalFieldManager();
            content.add(new LabelField("This is the tab content."));
            Pane panenew = new Pane(New,3);//Are the pane parameters right? 
            model.addPane(content, "The new Tab", null);//Can model be applied to this type?
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Blackberry does not have `TabSheet` and `Tab` classes.  In BBOS 6.0 and later, you can use the `PanelManagerModel`, `PaneManagerView`, `PaneManagerController`, and `Pane` classes instead.

Comment: Please see the reedits of what i have tried.It gives me strange errors.Any idea about the right implementation.

Comment: You can't use `PanelManagerModel` by itself, you have to use it in connection with `PaneManagerView` and `PaneManagerController` (Pane Managers use an MVC design).  The `Model` contains the data you want to display, the `View` actually displays the data, and the `Controller` manages the interactions between them. Look at the Pane Manager demo provided in the BB SDK.